# Jumping ship in this economy?

Tags: resignation, career-switch

There may not be a clear cut answer here, but this situation has been weighing down on me for some time and I would love to hear unbiased opinions other than my friends and family.

**Brief Overview**

I am currently a senior software engineer at company (A) and have been there for a little over 5 years. Recently I have been interviewing with company (B) and landed a senior software engineer position for a modest raise along with work from home, salary bonuses, similar perks, etc.

**The Situation**

I handed in my two weeks at company (A), however my boss was out of town at a convention and didn't return until yesterday (which was a holiday). We met and spoke in person and he convinced me to stay at my current role as the economy has taken a massive downturn since I accepted the offer at company (B). We also arranged an agreement to pay off all my outstanding debt, which is quite substantial.

Today was supposed to be my first day at company (B), and while this was extremely unprofessional, I contacted them to let them know I wouldn't be joining. Obviously my prospective supervisor was clearly disappointed, but just said "ok" and I thanked him for his time.

About ten minutes later I get a call from the recruiter who helped me get the position and we talked. She was obviously not super thrilled as well, but essentially said she could offer a sign on bonus that would essentially match the cash advance from my current employer at 20k as well as reassured me that the new company is *recession proof*.

**My Dilemma**

I am extremely confused on what to do as I am feeling that staying in my current role is the safe thing to do as I essentially have tenure and can eliminate my debts while taking a temporary pay cut for a year. One the other hand I could potentially take this sign on bonus as well as the raise, but risk jumping to a new company where I am uncertain what will happen if layoffs come down the pipeline.

Also now that current employer is aware I was about to jump ship, I feel that my loyalty will be in question and the new employer probably would have doubts as well from my lack of decisiveness. I know there won't be a clear cut answer here, but this is my first time resigning and potentially switching careers and I was hoping some people on here might have some valuable insight as I'm completely confused at this point in time.

San Francisco, Ca

Male 30s

Comment: Your explanation for accepting the counter offer is extremely confusing..  The economy hasn't changed a great deal in the last 2 weeks, I would argue it's been increasingly been getting worst for months, and trend will likely continue. The only question you have to ask yourself, has your current company, addressed the reasons you wanted to accept a new job. Hopefully, you accepted the counter offer, for more than the temporary monetary exchange. If the reasons you went looking for a job, have not actually been addressed, you will quickly find yourself unhappy.

Comment: @Donald a big motivation for the move was to quickly eliminate my debt and for a lesser reason just a change of scenery. I've been sitting on this offer for a little over a month debating making the switch, but recently I've been seeing a lot of headlines about major tech companies laying off quite large numbers of employees, especially new hires.

Comment: Those layoffs are the result of the downturn in the economy over months. There is a substantial cost to companies when they reduce their workforce by hundreds of employees.  Only you can determine if you feel comfortable at your current company. If your decision was fully based on your salary, that is fine, but keep in mind that your growth might be limited due to your substantial monetary reward today.

Comment: @Donald there is definitely a lot more here, but yeah I’m the end I know I’ll need to make the final decision. The answers below definitely have given me a bit more perspective on the pros and cons of making the switch right now. Thanks for comment!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I did reach out over the weekend, but as it was a long weekend I wasn’t able to speak to anyone until today. Part of that had to do with my boss only being able to meet me in person over the weekend as well.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yeah I realize how unprofessional it was the way I went about things and it's been weighing heavy on me as well. One thing I didn't mention was the new company wanted me to pay upfront for a flight / hotel to be onboarded in the coming weeks and I just did not have the cash on hand for that which made me feel like I would be first in line to be let go.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I would’ve taken the new position and ate ramen

Comment: @JoeStrazzere thanks for the response, you are completely right about being uncertain. Why a lot of this may sound confusing is probably from me backwards rationalizing decisions I mad after being swayed one way or the other by my current company and the new company.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you had a positive offer in hand that was a positive step forward, and you accepted a counter offer because you're concerned about the economy?

First, there is no such thing as a "recession proof" company. All companies feel it. They've given you a raise (that they could have given before you had this new offer) and filled your ears with honeyed words and platitudes like "recession proof".

You've just given them the time to find, hire, and train your replacement.

My answer is: You need to learn to be decisive and stick to your convictions. You had a reason for looking for a new job. That reason didn't go away even if it was couched in "higher pay". If you look at the situation from far enough out, you'll realize that you haven't improved anything except their ability to plan for your exit on their terms.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was afraid of, thank you for the insight

Comment: +1 for pointing out the fact no company is "recession proof", I would immediately not respond to that recruiter, since they are clearly not an honest person.  Sounds like a case where they spent a lot of time, to get you to accept the original deal, and will only get their reimbursement if you end of taking the job.  In other words they will say and do anything to get you to accept the "new" deal.

Comment: @Donald: It doesn't sound like the recruiter for the new job is the one that said that. I read it as his current manager who made the counter offer is the one who said it.

Answer (score 3):

I have been in a very similar situation, and I sympathize with how difficult weighing these options seems. Statistics say people who accept counter-offers from their current company end up staying about 6 months before leaving for various reasons. I actually stayed almost 2 more years before leaving for another much better offer.

Some things to consider that you haven't mentioned:

- Growth opportunities. Your new employer does things differently and likely uses different technology stacks. Gaining exposure and proficiencies is likely good for your career.
- Your current employer's counter offer likely contains payback clauses. I was offered a small one-time bonus that I'd have to pay back if I left in less than 2 years. I ended up staying 2 years, but I did not take that bonus because I wanted the opportunity to leave anytime. If they had been able to lock me in, I would be at their mercy
- Risk of new situation vs comfortability of current situation. In my experience, a lot of people are convinced to stay because they're OK with the "knowns" of their current situation, coworkers, boss, day-to-day activities, etc. I think this comfortability is detrimental so I'd push against accepting the status quo.
- Family ties. In my situation taking the position would mean relocating, and my daughter was very against moving. You didn't mention whether this is a consideration for you, but it was for me and maybe other readers. My Company B offer wasn't good enough to push me toward a dramatic relocation but my counter-offer from my Company A wasn't nearly as high as B's.

It sounds like you've already considered total compensation (first-time job/career changers might look mainly at salary and forget factors like bonuses, promotion potential, benefits, paid vacation time) which can influence a decision, and like I mentioned relocation can have a big impact as well.

Ultimately, I would recommend reading about reasons not to take a counter-offer as they make a pretty strong argument that staying is almost always not in your best interests. I didn't find these until after I chose to stay and it made me really rethink my decision (too late) and I'm glad another job opportunity came along shortly - it ended up being much better than my previous offer.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful!

Comment: Also just to answer something you mentioned the new position is remote while my current is hybrid.